# Binary Tree Search using Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, binary-tree, windows-forms-designer

As above I am developing an app that creates and sorts 10 integers. I need to be able to enter a integer in the search box, hit a search button and it should confirm whether or not the integer is there via messagebox. Below is my code.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeProject
{
    public partial class frmTask2 : Form
    {
        Tree MyTree;
        public frmTask2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       

        private void btnClose2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnDisplay2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num;
            lblUnsorted.Text = "";
            lblSorted.Text = "";
            num = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            lblUnsorted.Text = lblUnsorted.Text + num.ToString().PadLeft(3);
            MyTree = new Tree(num);

            for(int i = 1; i< 10; i++)
            {
                num = rnd.Next(0, 100);
                lblUnsorted.Text = lblUnsorted.Text + num.ToString().PadLeft(3);
                MyTree.AddRc(num);
            }
            string treestring = "";
            MyTree.Print(null, ref treestring);
            lblSorted.Text = treestring;
        }

       

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Required code here
        }

        private void lblUnsorted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    class Node
    {
        public int value;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        public Node (int initial)
        {
            value = initial;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    class Tree
    {
        Node top;

        public Tree()
        {
            top = null;
        }
        public Tree(int initial)
        {
            top = new Node(initial);
        }

        public void AddRc(int value)
        {
            //recurse add
            AddR(ref top, value);
        }

        private void AddR(ref Node N, int value)
        {
            // private recursive search for where to add the new node
            if (N == null)
            {
                Node NewNode = new Node(value);
                N = NewNode;
                return;
            }
            if (value < N.value)
            {
                AddR(ref N.left, value);
                return;
            }
            if (value >= N.value)
                {
                AddR(ref N.right, value);
                return;
            }
        }
        public Node search(Node root,
                   int key)
        {
            // Base Cases: root is null  
            // or key is present at root 
            if (root == null ||
                root.value == key)
                return root;

            // Key is greater than root's key 
            if (root.value < key)
                return search(root.right, key);

            // Key is smaller than root's key 
            return search(root.left, key);
        }

        public void Print(Node N, ref string s)
        {
            // write out the tree in sorted order to the string newstring using recursion
            if (N == null) { N = top; }
            if (N.left != null)
            {
                Print(N.left, ref s);
                s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);
            }
            else
            {
                s = s + N.value.ToString().PadLeft(3);
            }
            if (N.right != null)
            {
                Print(N.right, ref s);
            }
        }
        public bool ifNodeExists(Node node, int key)
        {
            if (node == null)
                return false;

            if (node.value == key)
                return true;

            // then recur on left sutree /
            bool res1 = ifNodeExists(node.left, key);

            // node found, no need to look further
            if (res1) return true;

            // node is not found in left, 
            // so recur on right subtree /
            bool res2 = ifNodeExists(node.right, key);

            return res2;
        }

    }
}
```

The tree works, I display the unsorted and sorted tree values via the labels but I'm stuck implementing the search button. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seahc button does not work? or works incorrectly?

Comment: So you have to 1) get the integer out of the input field, 2) call the search or ifNodeExists method of your tree, 3) display the outcome as MessageBox, Which of the three steps do you have problems with?

Comment: Hey Klaus thanks for the reply, 1 and 2.